# What are the best ways to monitor performance and maintain performance statistics of python code?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance

I'm working on a python multithreaded daemon that will be processing data through a variety of APIs.

The setup I have is:

the master daemon:
Manages the threads, sends messages to the thread queues.

the API threads:
one thread per API. This allows me to start Task #2 on API #1, while Task #1 is finishing up with the final API. There are 4 or 5 APIs (maybe 6?). Some of these APIs are web-based, some are java applications that I execute from the thread.

So, with this in place, I'd like to also setup something to monitor the cpu/memory usage of the daemon and its threads while this is running in production, and I'd like to save this information somewhere (flatfile? off site database?)

What are the best approaches to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use  **[psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/)** to retrieve information of running processes, and store wanted results using the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.